# inherit variable value from class to sub class c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 scenes each one have own script simply I want to get a value from script 1 and use it in script 2 which is loaded in the second scenes which happen is it always load the default value for this variable ex; if I call string variable which should have value (sas) it appears in the second script with null if integer it will be 0 although if I print it in the first script it will have the right value which "sas" .

look to method goforward () which update the variable x

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Trainbehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float force = (float)0.1;
    private Rigidbody sph;
    public GameObject button_goforward;
    public GameObject button_goright;
    public GameObject button_results;
    public GameObject button_nextlevel;
    public Text Results;



    public String x ;
    //public int g; 

    //public gamepbject panel ;
    //panel.gameobject.setactive(true);
    private void Start()
    {
        sph = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        button_goforward.SetActive(false);
        button_goright.SetActive(false);
        button_results.SetActive(false);
        button_nextlevel.SetActive(false);

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "switchtrigger")
        {
            button_goforward.SetActive(true);
            button_goright.SetActive(true);
            button_results.SetActive(true);


            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
    }

    public void goforward()
    {
        setx("sas");  // if a called print x it will be sas




     //   Results.text = "dzf";

    }


    public String getx()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public void setx(String x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
```

second script
in the update iam trying to get the value x by 
finalresults.text = trains.getx();

```
public class cases : Trainbehavior
{
    Trainbehavior trains;
    public Text finalresults;
    public string cx;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        trains = GetComponent<Trainbehavior>();
        /*var trainscript = gameObject.GetComponent<Trainbehavior>();
        if (trainscript)
        {


            finalresults.text = Results.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text;
        }*/
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // finalresults.text = trains.x;
        finalresults.text = trains.getx(); // if i called print(x) it will be null !
        /*
        var trainscript = gameObject.GetComponent<Trainbehavior>();
        if (trainscript)
        {
            // GameObject x = trainscript.GameObject.Find("test");
            finalresults.text = cx;
            print(cx);

        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest way is to make `x` `static`(`public static String x`) , but it isn't good method. I think you misunderstood about the concept of inheritance, instance and scene of unity. Refer these link. https://unity3d.com/kr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/inheritance
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: when i make it static in method setx  error : r'Trainbehavior.x' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Both "scripts" are two different instances. So setting the value on the one script will not set it on any other instance  ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you just want to call your `getx` function and return the value you set to `x` in the first script. However Unless you call that goForward function your not setting `x` and I don't see where your doing that. It looks like your saying when you do call `goforward` you get what you want which makes sense. you just need to call that `goforward` function in your second script to set `x` to a value before you call `getx`.

Your not inheriting `x` when you do this your just setting a public variable which is fine. you can either set the value to your public variable `x` in that function or anywhere in that class.

Comment: function go forward is called On click so when i click a button in the game it is called and it work fine but the problem is the value x remain null when i calll it in the second script